# PHP regex to allow newline didn't work

Tags: php, regex

PHP preg_match to accept new line

I want to pass every post/string through *PHP preg_match* function. I want to accept all the alpha-numerics and some special characters. Help me edit my syntax to allow newline. As the users fill textarea and press enter. Following syntax does not allow new line.

Please feedback whether following special characters are properly done or not
`*/_:,.?@;-*`

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z \/_:,.?@;-]+$/", $string)) { 
    echo 'good';
else {
    echo 'bad';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You were almost there!**

The `DOTALL` modifier mentioned by others is irrelevant to your regex.

To allow new lines, we just add `\r\n` to your character class. Your code becomes:

```
if (preg_match("/^[\r\n0-9a-zA-Z \/_:,.?@;-]+$/", $string)) { 
    echo 'good';
else {
    echo 'bad';
}
```

Note that this test and the regex can be written in a tidier way:

```
echo (preg_match("~^[\r\n\w /:,.?@;-]+$~",$string))? "***Good!***" : "Bad!";
```

See the result of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/53Gnd3) at the bottom.

- `\w` matches letters, digits and underscores, so we can get rid of them in the character class
- Changing the delimiter to a `~` allows you to use a `/` slash without escaping it (you need to escape delimiters)

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working. New line is not supported.

Comment: You're right! I had a typo. Fixed the answer and added [php demo](http://ideone.com/53Gnd3), please see the output at the bottom. :)

Comment: Your tidier way of writing, I applied. Your demo is working perfectly with new line. Now working, thank you. My bad, I used mysqli_real_escape_string(); It messed everything up.

Comment: Fantastic, glad to hear it! In that case could you please click the checkmark to the left of the answer to say that you accepted it? That's how the reputation system works here, accepting an answer gives reputation both to the answerer and to you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

it's always safe to add backslash to any non-alphanumeric characters so:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z \/\_\:\,\.\?\@\;\-]+$/
```

Also use character classes:

```
/^[[:alnum:] \/\_\:\,\.\?\@\;\-]+$/
```

oh about the new lines:

```
/^[[:alnum:] \r\n\/\_\:\,\.\?\@\;\-]+$/
```

to be able to do that string ^ (also, it'll be easier/safer to use single quotes)

```
'/^[[:alnum:] \\r\\n\/\_\:\,\.\?\@\;\-]+$/'
```

Comment: I add backslash to every special characters. Good to know that. So when string has paragraphs with many new lines. My syntax gives negative response for those.

Comment: oh, sorry was too lazy to read. lol. please see edited answer above

Comment: new line isn't working. I have a doubt. do we need to escape forwardslah \ too?

Comment: alright, I tested it, it works. maybe you didn't see the latest edit? please try it, thanks (the one with single quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternation to factor in the newlines:

```
/^(?:[0-9a-zA-Z \/_:,.?@;-]|\r?\n)+$/
```

Btw, you can shorten the expression a bit by replacing `[A-Za-z0-9_]` with `[\w\d]`:

```
/^(?:[\w\d \/:,.?@;-]|\r?\n)+$/
```

So:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:[\w\d \/:,.?@;-]|\r?\n)+$/', $string)) {
    echo "good";
} else {
    echo "bad";
}
```

Comment: It worked. After a long quest, I found one. thanks you. But your syntax allows which is No suppose to accept. like ( < blabla

Comment: @user3766078 `preg_match('/^(?:[\w\d \/:,.?@;-]|\r?\n)+$/', '< blabla');` doesn't match.

Comment: Your syntax do accept new line, but it accepts everything. which I don't want. Thank you

Comment: @user3766078 It doesn't accept everything, see the code in an earlier comment; please provide a working counter example.